# When do views get injected when using the AndroidAnnotations library?

Tags: android, android-annotations

I am wondering when `@ViewById`-annotated views are injected in AndroidAnnotations. Basically, I want to know if it is safe to access one of these views during onResume? I assume they are injected during onCreate but would like confirmation.

Thank you.

Comment: You are definitely safe to use a view annotated with `@ViewById` in `onResume`. If you need more precise information, I can investigate tomorrow.

Comment: Yea I would like to understand when initialization take place so I have better control in future. For example if I have a method with @AfterViews and the OnResume.. Which one executes first? If you can get me the info in an answer so I can accept then it would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to figure out exactly when injection happens is to inspect the code that AndroidAnnotations generates. For your examples, I made a simple Activity and Fragment as below:

```java
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @ViewById(R.id.textView)
    TextView textView;

    @AfterViews
    public void activityTestMethod() {

    }

}
```

```java
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_main)
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    @ViewById(R.id.imageView)
    ImageView imageView;

    @AfterViews
    public void fragmentTestMethod() {

    }

}
```

and then ran `./gradlew app:assembleDebug` to force AndroidAnnotations to generate the corresponding classes `MainActivity_` and `MainFragment_`. Let's look at `MainActivity_` first (irrelevant code omitted):

```java
public final class MainActivity_
    extends MainActivity
    implements HasViews, OnViewChangedListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        OnViewChangedNotifier previousNotifier = OnViewChangedNotifier.replaceNotifier(onViewChangedNotifier_);
        init_(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnViewChangedNotifier.replaceNotifier(previousNotifier);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void init_(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        OnViewChangedNotifier.registerOnViewChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
        onViewChangedNotifier_.notifyViewChanged(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewChanged(HasViews hasViews) {
        this.textView = hasViews.internalFindViewById(R.id.textView);
        activityTestMethod();
    }

}
```

The sequence of events that results in our views being bound and our `@AfterViews` methods being called is as follows:

- In `onCreate`, the `MainActivity_` instance is registered as an `OnViewChangedNotifier`.
- `onCreate` calls `setContentView`.
- `setContentView` calls `notifyViewChanged`, which triggers a (synchronous) call to `onViewChanged`.
- `onViewChanged` binds all fields annotated with `@ViewById`, *then* calls all methods annotated with `@AfterViews`.

Therefore, `@ViewById`-annotated views are bound and available for use after `onCreate` has been called, and `@AfterViews`-annotated methods will be executed at the end of `onCreate` and before any other Activity lifecycle method.

The story is similar for `MainFragment_`:

```java
public final class MainFragment_
    extends com.stkent.aatest.MainFragment
    implements HasViews, OnViewChangedListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        OnViewChangedNotifier previousNotifier = OnViewChangedNotifier.replaceNotifier(onViewChangedNotifier_);
        init_(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnViewChangedNotifier.replaceNotifier(previousNotifier);
    }

    private void init_(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        OnViewChangedNotifier.registerOnViewChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        onViewChangedNotifier_.notifyViewChanged(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewChanged(HasViews hasViews) {
        this.imageView = hasViews.internalFindViewById(R.id.imageView);
        fragmentTestMethod();
    }
}
```

The sequence of events that results in our views being bound and our `@AfterViews` methods being called is as follows:

- In `onCreate`, the `MainFragment_` instance is registered as an `OnViewChangedNotifier`.
- `onViewCreated` calls `notifyViewChanged`, which triggers a (synchronous) call to `onViewChanged`.
- `onViewChanged` binds all fields annotated with `@ViewById`, *then* calls all methods annotated with `@AfterViews`.

Therefore, `@ViewById`-annotated views are bound and available for use after `onViewCreated` has been called, and `@AfterViews`-annotated methods will be executed at the end of `onViewCreated` and before any other Fragment lifecycle method.

In both our examples, all view binding is performed in a lifecycle method that occurs much earlier than onResume, so you are safe to access them there :)

Comment: Wow amazing answer. This clears it up for sure. Thank you for your explanation:)